# Build installed but it won't open, iphone/ipad during development

Tags: ios

I had installed the app which is in development but when i open the app it shows a splash screen and after that application closes.

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue with this?

I am using the iPad2 version 5.0.1 (9a405).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a watchdog error. You're probably spending too much time in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` so the OS is closing your application. You only get about 5-10 seconds to launch, and after that you will be force closed. You should look to optimise your launch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your provisioning profile to this application has expired. Try to download and install it again. You can check profiles in device's settings.

Comment: i had checked its valid profile but same issue application opened and closed